# Evaluating the integral $\int_{B_1(0)} \frac{|x|}{x^2+y^2+z^2} d(x, y, z)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if there is an easy way to evaluate the integral

$$\int_{B_1(0)} \frac{|x|}{x^2+y^2+z^2} d(x, y, z)$$

where $B_1(0) = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1\}$ is the unit ball around $0$.

I know that usually, we could integrate first with respect to $x$, then to $y$ and then to $z$ (or in any other order), but I think that would get way to complicated here without any simplifications. I've noticed the $x^2 +y^2 + z^2$ in the denominator, and I know that the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by the points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1$. I think that will somehow help simplifying the integral; but I don't really know how exactly it helps us.

Comment: @moran Try using spherical coordinates.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari That sounds like a good idea. But I'm having trouble converting the expression in the integral into spherical coordinates. I know that the unit cube consists of all points (given in spherical coordinates) $(r, \phi, \theta)$, with $0 ≤ r < 1, \phi, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$. But how would I continue from there?